# doctrine oauth could not convert to array

Tags: doctrine-orm, oauth-2.0

I'm using doctrine2 with oauth2 and I always get an error on an oauth request to get a token.

```
Could not convert database value "xyz" to Doctrine Type array
```

What is the exact format for Client_OAuth2 grant_type column? I tried with serialized values and simple text... I need password as grant type. It works if grant_type is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grant_type` field define as `Array` in the entity. So, just use serialize value of an array for it's value.

Ex: if you want to save `array('client_credentials')`, save this serialize value on `grant_type` field `a:1:{i:0;s:18:"client_credentials";}`